# How does Slime coagulate and seal holes in tires?

Tags: tire, innertube, sealant

How do tire tube sealants like Slime coagulate and seal holes?

They can't coagulate like blood, because there's air already in the tube and they'd solidify. It also can't be in contact with moisture as there's a lot of moisture in tubes as well.

What's their sealing mechanism?

Comment: Not an answer as I don't know if this is the mechanism, but there are such things as anaerobic adhesives, which cure in the absence of air (the ones I used to use were for metals and wouldn't cure on anything else)

Comment: Yes, loctite (thread locker) works as an anaerobic adhesive, which is super fascinating to me.

Answer (score 4):

Most sealants work because they are actually a fibrous fluid or rubber solution.  When a puncture happens and the air pressure forces the fluid out a hole, the fibers create a plug or the rubber hardens.

http://www.velonews.com/2010/01/news/cyclocross/technical-faq-tire-sealants_102346

Comment: Yeah, my impression is that the "sliminess" of these products is due to tiny fibers.